# Sass compiler extension, Watch Sass don't compiling all sass files

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, sass

My project have 2 .scss files, but only one of them is compiling by extension. Maybe I need to compile manually?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have error there.
The variable named $blue1 is not found.

Comment: thats not problem here bro... I'm resolved this problem just changing scss files folder and watching sass again

Comment: looking your screenshot I see all the scss files have thier respective css and map files.